# What is a manhattan database?

Tags: database, data-warehouse

A friend of mine was interviewing for a data warehouse and Business Object role But he was  asked about the Manhattan database?

I have Googled "Manhattan database" and even searched for it on Bing and Yahoo but have found no relevant information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this? [Manhattan Data Warehouse](https://web.archive.org/web/20060616145249/http://manhattangroup.com/dw.asp)

Comment: Good find! dot dot dot (to appease S.O. minimum comment length. oh wait i passed the minimum several words ago.)

Comment: Probably this https://blog.twitter.com/2014/manhattan-our-real-time-multi-tenant-distributed-database-for-twitter-scale

Comment: This appears to be a defense oriented Personal Injury claims consulting service??

Comment: @Bakudan that one looks more likely.

Comment: Sometime in the last four years, the original site went away. I've updated the link to point to an archive.org copy.

Answer (score 1):

manhattan is the distributed db from twitter
https://blog.twitter.com/2014/manhattan-our-real-time-multi-tenant-distributed-database-for-twitter-scale

Comment: Do not copy someones else answer,this answer was given by Bakudan already in comment.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing may be **[Microsoft project Madison](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/parallel-data-warehouse.aspx)**, which is an auto-scalable data-warehouse appliance. The interviewer may have mixed-up Manhattan with Madison (Square Garden) which happens to be located in Manhattan.

Or, maybe he/she did it on purpose to see how good was your friend at data cleaning and conforming. :)

Comment: Thanks! Gentlemen for all the responses.

Just by reading Manhattan Data Warehouse project, I find it no different from Inmon CIF. Probably because any data warehouse design before DW2.0 is not copyrighted hence anyone can give it their own name. 

Cheers!